# Is it possible to move a particular JSON key to the top of the JSON using Javascript/VuejJS/Nodejs package?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vue-component

I have a web application built using the Vuejs within that I am obtaining a JSON from the Java backend service which has a format something like this:

```
{
  "a" : "Value-A",
  "c" : "Value-C",
  "b" : "Value-B",
  "schema" : "2.0"
}
```

Before displaying the result to the user I would like to move the `schema` to the top so that it would be easy for the user to read and I want it to look something like this:

```
{
  "schema" : "2.0",
  "a" : "Value-A",
  "c" : "Value-C",
  "b" : "Value-B"
}
```

As we can see only `schema` position has changed, the rest of the JSON as it is.

`Please Note`:

1. I am aware the JSON order does not matter but I am doing this for better readability purposes. If there is a way then it would be really useful for the reader to understand the JSON better.
2. I want to know if there is a direct way to do it rather than looping over the JSON, as my created JSON in the real application can be pretty large.
3. All I want to do is move the `schema` to the top of the JSON. The rest of the JSON can be as it is I do not want to make any modifications to it.
4. Is there a way to do this using vanilla Javascript or using some Nodejs library as I am using the Vuejs?

I would really appreciate it if there was a way to do it or is there any workaround for this.

Comment: _"I am aware the JSON order does not matter"_ - I do not think it's that the order doesn't matter, rather that it doesn't even guarantee any order at all. So the reordering might be straight-up ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *very* simplistic approach could be to stringify a new object.

```js
const myObject = {
  "a" : "Value-A",
  "c" : "Value-C",
  "b" : "Value-B",
  "schema" : "2.0"
};

console.log(
  JSON.stringify({
    schema: myObject.schema,
    ...myObject
  }, null, 2)
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, response and workaround. Worked like a charm. Have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is almost the same as the accepted answer but without using `JSON.stringify()`:

```js
const myObject = {
  "a" : "Value-A",
  "c" : "Value-C",
  "b" : "Value-B",
  "schema" : "2.0"
};

const myReorderedObject = {
  schema: '',
  ...myObject
};

console.log(myReorderedObject);
```